# Run rails Rake: test in Parallel (on multiple cores / speeding it up) using Miniest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, parallel-processing, rake

So running rake test (they are MiniTests) takes about 10 minutes for me (large rails project 95,000 lines of code in the /app directory). Its averaging about 25 assertions a second. The problem is there are a lot of tests.

Is there a way to run these in parallel (They are MiniTests)? I noticed only 1 core seems to be doing the work. Whats the best practice to execute these in Parallel?

mind you I am trying to best use all the resources (4-12 cores on the current machine the tests are running on). running them on separate machines isnt something i am looking at exploring currently.

so its impossible to concurrently run code on 2 cores at the same time with MRI i take it? using Jruby isnt an option currently.

Comment: Yes, there is a whole category dedicated to gems that help you execute tests in parallel: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/distributed_testing

Comment: parallel , is that focused on using different machines or different cores. reading up now thank!

Answer (score 1):

I think [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) can help you.

This gem will run some parallel tests, each in a separate process. In total you get ~100% loading on each your cores.